# Plotting empirical pdf plot using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, pdf

I would like to plot an empirical density plot (pdf), of a column of data that I have. The example I am going after, looks like this:

[image]

just without all the white lines in the background. However, I am quite unsure as to which "route" to take; I have a `.csv` with all the datapoints, so maybe this is one way to go? Or maybe it is simply better estimating a function, which is easier and more light for LaTeX to handle?

Comment: Depending on what else is in that CSV, pgfplot can easily plot xy data from external files. There are many example floating around if you search for them

Comment: Yeah, I actually just tried that, but it said that the max capacity of Latex was reached. Probably due to the .csv having 14,000 rows of data (for x and y)?

Comment: Then try with lualatex instead. Do you really need 14000 datapoints?